# Trying to add validation but get NameError in Posts#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to add validation to my blog posts so when you try to add a title less than 5 chars you get an error message  , but at the moment i get this error message -

```
NameError in Posts#create
& undefined local variable or method `msg' for #<#<Class:0x007fce95ca04c0>:0x007fce95b4a300>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class = "container">
    <h1> New Post </h1>

        <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>

    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do [msg] %>
            <li><%= msg %></li> <error

            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
        <%= f.label :text %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
    <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController


        def index
            @posts = Post.all
        end

        def new
            @post = Post.new
        end

        def create
            @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

            if @post.save
                redirect_to @post
            else
                render 'new'
            end
        end

        def show
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

        private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
        end


    end
```

**post.rb**

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

        validates :title, presence: true,
                            length: { minimum: 5 }
    end
```

Comment: Can you post your new.html.erb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do [msg] %>
```

Should be like this

```
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
```